# Pythonic equivalent of Java marker annotations

Tags: python, annotations

I want to search my Python classpath for all classes that can handle a certain input (type), at runtime. Then I will instantiate them and call them when I receive that input. I would like each class author to be able to mark their class as a possible handler.

In Java, I can define the annotation `@Handler` and do this:

```java
@Handler
public class MyHandler implements HandlerInterface {
    // whatever
}
```

then get the set of all marked classes like this with the Reflections library (or Spring Framework if I'm using it):

```java
Set<Class<?>> handlerClasses = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Handler.class);
```

What is the Python equivalent?

`@decorator` doesn't seem to fulfill quite the same goal; it seems to be entirely for wrappers, whereas that's just one possible use of Java's `@` syntax.

I can almost do it with inheritance instead:

```py
class MyHandler(HandlerInterface):
    pass

handlers = [
    handler() for handler in HandlerInterface.__subclasses__()
]
```

But that solution may get intermediate classes (e.g. `HandlerInterface` -> `HandlerType1` -> `HandlerType1Implementation`).

Am I missing any other options? Or is there a different design pattern I should be looking at? I may be looking at it from a too Java-centric point of view.

Comment: There is no such annotation. Instead you want to structure your code as pub/sub.

Answer (score 0):

> `@decorator` doesn't seem to fulfill quite the same goal; it seems to be entirely for wrappers, whereas that's just one possible use of Java's `@` syntax.

This isn't right. In Python, `@<arbitrary expression>` is able to execute arbitrary code as long as [`<arbitrary expression>`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) evaluates to an instance which is compatible with the following interface:

```py
import collections.abc as cx
import typing as t

DecorateeT = t.TypeVar("DecorateeT", bound=cx.Callable[..., t.Any], contravariant=True)
ReturnT = t.TypeVar("ReturnT", covariant=True)

class Decorator(t.Protocol[DecorateeT, ReturnT]):
    def __call__(self, decoratee: DecorateeT, /) -> ReturnT: ...
```

Here, `DecorateeT` can be any one of the following [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=compound%20statement#compound-statements):

- A [class definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=compound%20statement#class-definitions)
- A [function defnition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=compound%20statement#function-definitions)
- A [coroutine function definition](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html?highlight=compound%20statement#coroutine-function-definition)

For example, the following all implement a decorator which replaces class definitions in a module with `None`:

```py
def classErasingFunction(class_: type, /) -> None:
    return None

classErasingLambda: Decorator[type, None] = lambda _: None

class ClassRecorderAndEraser:
    _erased_classes: t.ClassVar[list[type]] = []

    def __call__(self, class_: type, /) -> None:
        type(self)._erased_classes.append(class_)
        return None

    @classmethod
    def getErasedClasses(cls) -> cx.Sequence[type]:
        return cls._erased_classes

recordAndErase = ClassRecorderAndEraser()
```

```
>>> @classErasingFunction
... class A: pass
...
>>> @classErasingLambda
... class B: pass
... 
>>> @lambda _: None  # Requires Python 3.9+; see PEP 614
... class C: pass
...
>>> @recordAndErase
... class D: pass
...
>>> @ClassRecorderAndEraser()
... class E: pass
...
>>> print(A, B, C, D, E)
None None None None None
>>> recordAndErase.getErasedClasses()
[<class 'D'>, <class 'E'>]
```

---

With this, here's a minimal implementation of `Handler` in Python to somewhat match the Java API:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx
    HandlerInterfaceT = t.TypeVar("HandlerInterfaceT", bound=type["HandlerInterface"])

class _HandlerDecoratorFactory:
    _decorated_types: list[type[HandlerInterface]]

    def getDecoratedTypes(self) -> cx.Sequence[type[HandlerInterface]]:
        return self._decorated_types

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._decorated_types = []

    def __call__(self, HandlerClass: HandlerInterfaceT, /) -> HandlerInterfaceT:
        self._decorated_types.append(HandlerClass)
        return HandlerClass


Handler: t.Final = _HandlerDecoratorFactory()

class HandlerInterface: pass
```

```
>>> @Handler
... class MyHandler(HandlerInterface): pass
...
>>> class HandlerType1(HandlerInterface): pass
...
>>> @Handler
... class HandlerType1Implementation(HandlerType1): pass
...
>>> Handler.getDecoratedTypes()
[<class 'MyHandler'>, <class 'HandlerType1Implementation'>]
```

---

Is this "Pythonic"? Well, this kind of API is natively supported in Python, and  if you statically-type your API properly, you can catch the equivalent of compile-time type errors:

```py
@Handler
class Not_A_Handler:  # mypy: Value of type variable "HandlerInterfaceT" of "__call__" of "_HandlerDecoratorFactory" cannot be "type[Not_A_Handler]"
    pass
```

Rather than worrying about whether this is Pythonic, I would figure out whether there is a need to write Java-esque code in Python for your use case.